# Is there a way to automatically take multiple screenshots of a video?

Tags: video, automation

I want to take N screenshots equally spaced out on a video of some format(FLV, mp4, etc). Is there program or a script to a way to automate this?

Comment: Related: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=93803&hilit=ncat

Comment: Could you clarify? Would you want screenshots **of** a video (like in the title), or screenshots of your computer-screen to (or on) a video (like in the question). If it's the first you can use the answer of BrianZ , if it's the second the link Moses gave gives you the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This blog post](http://www.labnol.org/software/extract-image-frames-from-video/) lays out a few options and the following examples are taken from there. With [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) you could do something like:

`C:\VideoLAN\VLC>vlc "C:\videos\hello.mov" --video-filter=scene 
   --vout=dummy --start-time=1 --stop-time=5 --scene-ratio=1 
   --scene-prefix=img- --scene-path=C:\images\ vlc://quit`

With ffmpeg, the sample command is:

```
c:\ffmpeg.exe -i c:\video\hello.mov –ss 10 –t 4 img-%03d.jpg
```

Comment: I corrected your command. It was full of syntax errors and old options. Left a comment on the blog entry and hope they will correct it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking for as the question currently stands, but if you want a set of thumbnail images spanning the entire timespan of a video, Media Player Classic has an option from a paused video. Click on: file > save thumbnails

Answer (score 1):

A simpler command for FFMPEG to create 60 second interval clips is like this:

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.avi -vf fps=1/60 img%03d.jpg
```

This command can be adjusted to take quicker or slower intervals by modifying the fps key. In this example, it takes 1 frame per 60 seconds.

There is a blog guide on it here with details instructions: https://www.theaudiodb.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2017

Comment: There is a quick blog guide here with further details https://www.theaudiodb.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2017

Comment: How should the OP adapt your command if they want to use some other interval? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.  While you’re at it, you should probably put the link to the guide *into your answer* as well.